# experimentalDecorators Warning on ts lint

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

I'm getting typescript ts link warning, fired by the vs code. I get that when I mouse over the Service name which is HttpService which is underlined for some reason I cannot figure out.

> [ts] Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject
>   to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option
>   to remove this warning. class HttpService

I mean I can do this on the `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowJs": true
    }
}
```

and that will remove the error, but, this is not a good practice as it sweeps the dirt under the carpet only for the time being.

What is it that we need to do so we do not have to deal with this?

Is there something wrong almost in a barebone boilet plate code here?

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, ResponseContentType} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  getData(url: any) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    // headers.append('','');
    return this.http.get(url )
      .map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is warning you that the line:

```
@Injectable()
```

Is *technically* an experimental feature.

You need to update your tsconfig.json with:

```
//...
"experimentalDecorators": true,
//...
```

Comment: Interesting.. Wasn't the angular team the one who suggested to everyone that even if you are not gonna use it, it is best practice to put it in as such??

Comment: Well, I just did `// @Injectable()` and the HttpService is no longer underline. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @AverageJoe - I am using experimental decorators, it isn't 100% stable, but it is pretty unavoidable, expecially if you are using Angular.

Comment: it is interesting but... experimentalDecorators WAS set to true already. I realized this when I saw that red line under a component! So all decorates are being looked down upon. I thought only the @injectable one which had its own no-use situation...

Comment: How do you get away with not using the decorators in Components. How do you pass your template, styles and selector?

Comment: I have experimentalDecorators set to true in my tsconfig file and VSCode is still reporting an error!